# Confusion in data types in a 2D array

Tags: c, pointers

Here is a code which print the address of the first element of an 2D array followed by an addition of 1. Though all 4 base addresses are same but their addition with 1 is obviously not giving the same result due the their different "types". I can figure out the type for some(in case they are correct) but not for all.

```
int main()
{
    int array[4][3];
    printf("array %u\n",array);   //of type int(*)[3]
    printf("array+1 %u\n",array+1);
    printf("&array %u\n",&array);   //....???
    printf("&array+1 %u\n",&array+1);
    printf("array[0] %u\n",array[0]);    //of type int*
    printf("array[0]+1 %u\n",array[0]+1);
    printf("&array[0] %u\n",&array[0]); //....???
    printf("&array[0]+1 %u\n",&array[0]+1);
}
```

Can you explain the "type" of each base address in detail in order to understand the pointer arithmetic involved after adding 1. A sample output for gcc machine is given below for quick reference.

```
array       3214383040 
array+1     3214383052 
&array      3214383040 
&array+1    3214383088 
array[0]    3214383040 
array[0]+1  3214383044 
&array[0]   3214383040 
&array[0]+1 3214383052
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Having `int array[4][3];` the following applies

`array` is an array with 4 elements. Each element is an array with 3 `int`s. In most circumstances using the name by itself makes the array decay to a pointer to its first element; then `array` becomes a pointer to arrays of 3 `int`s

`array + 1` is a pointer to an array of 3 ints. Here `array` decays to pointer and the `1` refers to array of 3 `int`

`&array` is the address of the whole array. It points to objects of type array of 4 arrays of 3 ints

`&array + 1` is the 2nd (which really does not exist) element of a *pseudo-*array of arrays of 4 arrays of 3 ints

`array[0]` is an array of 3 ints. It usually decays to a pointer to the first element

`array[0] + 1` points to the 2nd `int` in `array[0]`

`&array[0]` address of an object of type array of 3 ints

`&array[0]+1` 2nd element of an array of arrays of 3 ints

*PS. I'll try to make a drawing (ASCII) after lunch.*

---

*Hmmm ... drawing is tough :)*

Before trying, I thought I could make a better drawing.
This is the best I could come up with ...

```
    int array[4][3]        ........[aaabbbcccddd]........
                              where aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd are arrays of 3 ints'

    the [] represent the object itself; the {} represent pointers.

    array (object)         ........[AAABBBCCCDDD]........       int[4][3]
    array (decayed)    ==> ........{aaa}bbbcccddd........       int(*)[3]

    array + 1          ==> ........aaa{bbb}cccddd........       int(*)[3]

    &array             ==> ........{aaabbbcccddd}........       int(*)[4][3]
    &array + 1         ==> ........aaabbbcccddd{xxxxxxxxxxxx}........       int(*)[4][3]

    array[0] (object)      ........[AAA]bbbcccddd........       int[3]
    array[0] (decayed) ==> ........{a}aabbbcccddd........       int*

    array[0] + 1       ==> ........a{a}abbbcccddd........       int*

    &array[0]          ==> ........{aaa}bbbcccddd........       int(*)[3]
    &array[0] + 1      ==> ........aaa{bbb}cccddd........       int(*)[3]
```

Comment: I am satisfied with your answer but it will be great if you will supplement the drawings. Will wait some time before accepting it.

Answer (score 3):

If you compile this as C++, you can use the `typeid` operator from the `typeinfo` STL library to get this information.  For example, running this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <typeinfo>

void main()
{
     int array[4][3];
     printf("array %s\n",typeid(array).name());   //of type int(*)[3]
     printf("array+1 %s\n",typeid(array+1).name());
     printf("&array %s\n",typeid(&array).name());   //....???
     printf("&array+1 %s\n",typeid(&array+1).name());
     printf("array[0] %s\n",typeid(array[0]).name());    //of type int*
     printf("array[0]+1 %s\n",typeid(array[0]+1).name());
     printf("&array[0] %s\n",typeid(&array[0]).name()); //....???
     printf("&array[0]+1 %s\n",typeid(&array[0]+1).name());
}
```

Gave me the following results

```
array int [4][3]
array+1 int (*)[3]
&array int (*)[4][3]
&array+1 int (*)[4][3]
array[0] int [3]
array[0]+1 int *
&array[0] int (*)[3]
&array[0]+1 int (*)[3]
```

This explains why adding 1 can increase the pointer by 4 bytes (a single int), 12 bytes (int[3]) or by 48 bytes (int[4][3]).

Comment: Nice alternative to find it directly. It just slipped off my mind.