# Difference between pointer to pointer and pointer to array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, declaration, dereference

Given that the name of an array is actually a pointer to the first element of an array, the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a[3] = {0, 1, 2};
    int *p;

    p = a;

    printf("%d\n", p[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

prints `1`, as expected.

Now, given that I can create a pointer that points to a pointer, I wrote the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                              

int main(void)                                                                  
{                                                                               
        int *p0;                                                                
        int **p1;                                                               
        int (*p2)[3];                                                           
        int a[3] = {0, 1, 2};                                                   

        p0 = a;                                                                 
        p1 = &a;                                                                
        p2 = &a;                                                                

        printf("p0[1] = %d\n(*p1)[1] = %d\n(*p2)[1] = %d\n",                    
                        p0[1], (*p1)[1], (*p2)[1]);                             

        return 0;                                                               
}
```

I expected it to compile and print

```
p0[1] = 1
(*p1)[1] = 1
(*p2)[1] = 1
```

But instead, it goes wrong at compile time, saying:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:11:5: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
```

Why is that assignment wrong? If `p1` is a pointer to a pointer to an `int` and `a` is a pointer to an `int` (because it's the name of an array of `int`s), why can't I assign `&a` to `p1`?

Comment: Sometime ago I wrote [an answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181237/confusion-in-data-types-in-a-2d-array) you might like.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Line 11 is

```
        p1 = &a;
```

where `p1` has type `int **` and `a` has type `int[3]`, right?

Well; `&a` has type `int(*)[3]` and that type is not compatible with `int**` as the compiler told you

You may want to try

```
        p1 = &p0;
```

And read [the c-faq](http://c-faq.com), particularly section 6.

In short: **arrays are not pointers**, and **pointers are not arrays**.

Comment: That kind of subverts everything I thought I knew about arrays and pointers. I'm wondered by how did I get away with this for so many years, really. Thank you for making it clear.

Comment: @jpmelos - The way arrays and pointers work is surprisingly subtle, and not something that's very easy to make clear early on in learning C. Glad you got it.

Comment: You got away with it because very often arrays behave as pointers and pointers behave as arrays ... **but they're not the same!** Read [the c-faq](http://c-faq.com/) section 6: it's really interesting :)

Answer (score 7):

`a` is not a pointer to `int`, it *decays* to such in certain situations. If `&a` was of type `int **` you couldn't very well use it to initialize `p2`, could you?

You need to do `p1 = &p0;` for the effect you want. "pointer to pointer" means "at this address, you will find a pointer". But if you look at the address `&a`, you find an array (obviously), so `int **` is not the correct type.

Comment: Then, what is stored under the name `a`, if not an address to the first element of `a` (which would be the pointer I was looking for)?

Comment: @jpmelos - `a` is an array. It stores the actual array elements. The name of an array decays to a pointer to the first element when passed to a function, but that doesn't mean that arrays are implemented as pointers to an area. `int a[3];` on its own makes no pointers, just three `int`s.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your comment helped me enlighten my thoughts a little bit further!

Answer (score 0):

For many operations, `a` implies `&a` and both return the same thing: The address of the first item in the array.

You cannot get the address of the pointer because the variable does not store the pointer. `a` is not a pointer, even though it behaves like one in some cases.

Comment: @jpmelos - Because the type of `&a` is `int (*)[3]` rather than `int **`.

Comment: No! `a` does not imply `&a` for many things. It implies `&a[0]` !