# How does this C program compile and run successfully?

Tags: c

I was asked this in an interview. What will be the result of this program? I confidently said that this will not compile. I said that a is an array name and does not take up any space, so &a should not make any sense, hence this will not compile. but on hands-on, it turns out that compiles as well as runs successfully. Could someone please explain, how this works.

```
main()    
{
    int a[50];
    &a; // or perhaps the interviewer wanted to know the output of this line..
}
```

Comment: "a" is a pointer to the array.

Comment: An array does take up space in memory (where else would you store its contents), so it's perfectly reasonable to retrieve the address of the array.

Comment: See [an old(ish) answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181237/confusion-in-data-types-in-a-2d-array/5181495#5181495) for related information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `&a;` line just computes the address of the array `a`, and silently discards it.

Comment: then what's the difference between a and &a. I thought a is starting address of array. but looks like &a also has the same thing? or perhaps a and &a have same value, but a+1 and &a + 1 will have diff value.

Comment: a is equivalent to &a where a is an array. See this explanation: http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/arrayptr/arraysaspointers2.html

Comment: ok, got the basic idea. the program at https://ideone.com/0f7Tk illustrates the diff btw a+1 and &a + 1.

Comment: No it doesn't silently discard. This is old K&R C, where the last statement of a function designates its return value.

Comment: @p2pnode: the expressions `a` and `&a` will have the same value (the address of the first element of the array), but the *types* of the expressions are different - `int *` and `int (*)[50]`, respectively.

Answer (score 3):

This program has no observable result. It is compiled successfully but doesn't have any observable behavior.

`&a` is an expression. Because `a` is an object of array type, `&a` is the address of the array(its value may coincide with `&a[0]`, but its type doesn't - `int*` vs `int(*)[50]`). Any expression followed by a semicolon is an expression statement. A function body is a sequence of zero or more statements enclosed in `{}` Therefore this is a legitimate `main()` function. (When you write `a[0] = 10;` this too is an expression statement.)

Under the as-if rule of the C++ standard, the implementation may even decide not to allocate any memory for your array, and do nothing at all, because even if it did, you wouldn't have any way to check it (at least from C++ point of view).

The following is also a valid C++ program

```
int main()
{
   1; 2; 3;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The interviewer clearly should got new test material :) This…

> ```
> main()    
> {
>     int a[50];
>     &a;
> }
> ```

… is old K&R C. If not declared otherwise a function returns `int` and the last statement of the function is returned implicitly. You can rewrite this to ANSI C the following:

```
int main()    
{
    int a[50];
    return &a;
}
```

So lets dissect this program:

---

```
int main()
```

Define a function `main` returning an `int`, taking arbitrary parameters.

---

```
{
    int a[50];
```

Define an array of 50 `int` in automatic storage and assign <s>an `int` pointer (`int*`) to the first element of</s> this array to variable of the literal `a`.

---

```
    return (intptr_t)&a;
}
```

Now this is a bit tricky. Just writing `a` evaluates to the address of the *first element of the* array. The `&` operator takes the address of the <s>variable this particular pointer is stored in. It doesn't matter that there are 50 `int` allocated somewhere and this variable currently points there. What we take is the pointer to the pointer, i.e. an `int` pointer pointer (`int**`).</s>array, again its first element.

However K&R C defines implicit conversion of pointer types to integers. The value of this pointer uniquely identifies the original pointer and must be suited for pointer arithmetic. Most compilers implement this by simply storing the verbatim address of the pointer in the integer. Important exception: Any special machine dependent nil-pointer value must map to 0 on the C side and an `int` or `intptr_t` of 0 cast to a pointer must map to the architecture nil value (on most architectures the machine nil value is 0, too).

`main` returns the integer representation of the pointer, on most system its memory address, which by definition of the C standard designates it's exit code.

---

Compiling this program

```
cc -o interview_question interview_question.c
```

You can execute and display its exit code using

```
./interview_question ; echo $?
```

Which will be some arbitrary, but not a random number.

**EDITs due to @John Bodes comment and corrections.**

Comment: Quibbles: `a` is an array, not a pointer; it will have its type implicitly converted to a pointer in most circumstances.  Secondly, the type of `&a` is `int (*)[50]`, not `int **`.

Comment: This is not necessarily K&R C. If I compile with gcc (as a .c file) and run I get a garbage return code. (The compiler is treating it as old K&R.) However, if I compile with g++ (as a .cpp file) and run I get a zero return code. That final &a is dropped on the floor and the program does a return 0 (see ISO/IEC 14882:2003 3.6.1 ¶ 5).

Comment: @David Hammen: Well yes, because C++ explicitly requires a functions return value stated in the `return` statement. But I'm surprised that a C++ would actually compile at all the OP's code (OTOH I don't know the C++ standard in that detail as I know C; and also my C knowledge is not complete, I'm still learning – see my first version of the answer, John's comment and compare with how I changed my answer).

Answer (score 2):

you can use an expression as a statement, it's perfectly valid. It won't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

This code should compile and run successfully as I feel. 
a is an array,
&a is nothing but the address of first index (same as a). so &a is an expression which doesn't do anything ...
its same as:

int x;
&x;

There will not be any output of this as expression 2 is doing nothing.