# referenced array == array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, reference

could you tell my why the value of a referenced
array and the value of the array itself has the same value?

i know a is a type of int* but with &a it should be int** or am i wrong??
so the value should be a pointer to the a int pointer.
example code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        int a[10];
        printf("a without ref.: 0x%x\n",a);
        printf("a with    ref.: 0x%x\n",&a);
        return 0;
    }
```

http://ideone.com/KClQJ

Comment: possible duplicate of [C: How come an array's address is equal to its value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/c-how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value)

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7351331/51831

Comment: You might like [an answer of mine to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181237/confusion-in-data-types-in-a-2d-array/5181495#5181495) asked some time ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Name of the array decays to an pointer to its first element in this case.

Comment: I don't think it's the *name* that decays. The array itself decays :) +1 anyway

Answer (score 1):

Name of the array will implicit convert to a pointer ,except for two situation ,the one situations is "&array",the other is "sizeof(array)".In both cases,name of the array is a array ,not a pointer .

For example:

```
int a[10];
int *p;
p = a;        //a is a pointer
p = &a;       //a is a array,&a is a constant pointer
sizeof(a);    //a is array
```

Answer (score 1):

Given an array declaration `T a[N]`, the expression `&a` has type "pointer to N-element array of `T` (`T (*)[N]`) and its value is the base address of the array.  In that respect, the unary `&` operator behaves the same for arrays as it does for any other data type.

What's hinky is how C treats the array expression `a`.  Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an array expression of type "N-element array of `T`" (`T [N]`) will be replaced with ("decay to") a pointer expression of type "pointer to `T`" (`T *`) and its value will be the address of the first element of the array.  IOW, `a == &a[0]`.

Since the address of the first element of the array is the same as the base address of the entire array, the expressions `a` and `&a` yield the same *value*, but the types are different (`T *` as opposed to `T (*)[N]`).

Answer (score 0):

if there is int *p which point a, then,

a+0 == &a[0] == p+0 == &p[0] : address

*(a+0) == *(&a[0]) == *(p+0) == *(&p[0]) : data

a == &a == &a[0]

Comment: The **types** of `a` and `&a` are not the same (though the values are): you cannot say that 42 carrots is the same as 42 potatoes.